# Bulk Rename Utility How to delete end of filename part start with a char?

Tags: regex, rename, bulk

Here is my issue :
original name is **xxxxxxxxAyyyyyyy.jpg** where **xxxxxxxx** is anything (any char and any number of chars) except the **'A'** and **yyyyyyy** is anything (any char and any number of chars).

=> Expected result is **xxxxxxxx.jpg**

Do I need complex regex ?

**A** is only one (but any) char in my case but answer for multiple chars could be interesting and integrate single char too.

```
example with -: my name is - james bond.html => my name is .html
example with a: my name is - james bond.html => my n.html
```

My OS is Windows 10

Comment: Could there be multiple `A` characters? If so, which delimits the `x` from the `y` fields? If you want to avoid regular expressions, you can use `for` or `find` with `mv` and `bash` parameter expansion.

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: I had never heard of Bulk Rename Utility but there is a Windows program by that name so I guess Windows. If this is the case, I have no idea about that utility but you could do it easily enough in powershell if you are open to that for answers.

Comment: As a follow-up with @afh's comment: A is a very common letter, how would you use your scheme to split `catastrophicMassDeleteFiles.txt` into three fields?

Comment: Complement : A is single but multiple char is also interesting. A is any character, not present in xxxxxxx otherwise it doesn't work. Windows 10.  Bulk Rename Utility is the most powerful graphical utility to do this job (you see result before applying)

Comment: So can **A** be in the **yyyyyyy** part?

Comment: So can A be in the yyyyyyy part? Yes **A** is the startup delimiter

Comment: Your example with `a` is inconsistent. From your problem definition it should be: `example with a: my name is - james bond.html => my n.html`.

Comment: @AFH. You're right

Comment: @Yorick catastrophicMassDeleteFiles.txt yyyyy part with **A** delimiter is simply empty!

Comment: You can form the new name in `cmd` by using [advanced variable expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html) within a `for` loop. Since it involves a number of commands, you will probably want to place them in a batch file, so that you don't need to type them all every time you want to do the renaming. If you want to make it more general-purpose, you can elaborate the batch file to use parameters for some of the file definitions.

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution if **A** is single char :[Bulk Rename Utility param](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZPW1.png)